# Raspberry Pi3 not rendering vpython drawings using Chromium browser

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian, vpython

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 A+ on which I installed the vpython using a pip command. When I try to execute a very simple set of commands in python it doesn't work:

```
from vpython import
ball=sphere(radius=2,color=color.red)
```

It opens the Chromium Browser but it doesn't show anything (it is a blank page). What should I do in order to make it show the red ball like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%5C_q5t46kIC30&t=593s

I tried a few advices from ChatGPT like updating the chromium:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade chromium-browser
```

or trying to modify the amount of memory in use for the gpu from 64M to 128M but it only made the raspberry pi slower and it didn't work.

Comment: Your first line should be "from vpython import *"